# Show data from array into checkbox such that If the same data is in another array, it will show checkbox as checked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an array containing all values let say
`arr1 = [{"Name":"Mr.X"},{"Name":"Mr.Y"},{"Name":"Mr.Z"} ]`.

I'm also having another array with few values like `arr2 = [{"Name":"Mr.Z"}]`.

**I want to show all the data from arr1 as checkbox such that if the data exist in arr2, it will show as a checked checkedbox. In this case Mr.Z should be checked by default and other two should be unchecked.**

I have tried this but my data is now showing multiple times due to two loops.

```
{arr1.map((name1) =>
    arr2.map((name2) =>
    name1.Name === name2.Name ? (
        <FormControlLabel
             control={
                 <Checkbox
                     checked={true}
                     name="Name"
                     color="primary"
                     disabled={editable}
                 />
             }
             label={name.Name}
        />
        ) : (
            <FormControlLabel
                 control={
                     <Checkbox
                          name="Name"
                          color="primary"
                          disabled={editable}
                    />
                 }
                 label={name.Name}
            />
      )
))}
```

Please let me know what approach should i apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something among the lines of:

```
arr1.map((arrItem) =>
        (
            (arr2.find(u => u.Name === arrItem.Name)) ?
            console.log(arrItem.Name + " checked")
            :
            console.log(arrItem.Name + " unchecked")
        ))
```

When given your input, this produces:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5qQQ.png)

Comment: No It's not giving me the desired result.

Comment: I've updated the comment above to reflect your updated variable names. Where/how does it fall short of the desired result?